# How about the register resource situation when all threads quit(return) except one?

Tags: cuda

I'm writing a CUDA program with the dynamic parallelism mechanism, just like this:

```
{

if(tid!=0) return;

else{

 anotherKernel<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>();

}
```

I know the parent kernel will not quit until the child kernel function finishes its work.is that mean other threads' register resource in the parent kernel(except tid==0) will not be retrieved? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

When and how a terminated thread's resources (e.g. register use) are returned to the machine for use by other blocks is unspecified, and empirically seems to vary by GPU architecture.  The reasonable candidates here are that resources are returned at completion of the block, or at completion of the warp.

But that uncertainty need not go beyond the block level.  A block that is fully retired returns its resources to the SM that it was resident on for future scheduling purposes. It does not wait for the completion of the kernel.  This characteristic is self-evident(*) as being a necessity for the proper operation of a CUDA GPU.

Therefore for the example you have given, we can be sure that all threadblocks except the first threadblock will release their resources, at the point of the `return` statement.  I cannot make specific claims about when exactly warps in the first threadblock may release their resources (except that when thread 0 terminates, resources will be released at that point, if not before).

(*) If it were not the case, a GPU would not be able to process a  kernel with more than a relatively small number of blocks (e.g. for the latest GPUs, on the order of several thousand blocks.)  Yet it is easy to demonstrate that even the smallest GPUs can process kernels with millions of blocks.

Comment: thanks a lot，you said the release of the block which contains a thread which has such behaviour like my code is not certain .is that possible mean that the resource release depends on my next code? if  I do nothing just launch the sub-kernel，how about this situation?

Comment: The thing that is not certain, is whether resources will be released at the completion of a warp, or only at the completion of a block.  But certainly, at the completion of *any* block, its resources are released.  No, this does not depend on your "next code".

Comment: OK, I got. Thanks a lot, sir. would you mind me ask you another question?  is there any benefit exist on calculating by using the Cuda vectors such as float4? I know it can speed up the load/store operation, However, I'm not sure about its computational efficiency. Is its behavior similar to SIMD, or just like the ordinary vectors?